# How can I get all of touch events in my activity even in drag mode?

Tags: android, touch, screen

I want to get x and y position of every touch point in my activity even in drag mode. When I implement `onTouchEvent` method of my activity, it does not get all of touch events. How can I do that?

Thanks in advance,

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        // my Code
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
}
```

This onTouchEvent method just rises when you touch around the activity.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have any other View which handle touch events?

The [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onTouchEvent%28android.view.MotionEvent%29) says:

> Called when a touch screen event was not handled by any of the views
>   under it. This is most useful to process touch events that happen
>   outside of your window bounds, where there is no view to receive it.

So when you say you don't get any events when you are in drag mode, this implies that you're dragging some thing. So you already handling the events somewhere else and therefore the onTouchEvent() method won't be notified.

You can try to return false in the other TouchListener's onTouch() method so the event will bubble up further more.

Comment: No. there is no TouchListener. I removed my drag procedure and I still have problem. I have a ScrollView. When I touch outside of ScrollView, the onTouchEvent method of activity works fine but when I touch inside of ScrollView it does not work.

Comment: Then the ScrollView catches the events as it has to scroll the Views it surrounds. So the events are already handled and won't reach the onTouchEvent() method of your Activity. This behavior makes totally sense. Imaging what would happen when you have a draggable element within the ScrollView and you start dragging it from top to bottom? Should the item be dragged or should the whole screen be scrolled? You see what the problem is?

Comment: I removed that ScrollView and now I can get touch events when there is no drag operation on my activity. But I have to do drag operation. I mean when I enable dragging in that page, I can not get the touch event. The main question is How can I detect the mouse (touch) position while I am dragging?

Comment: What do you mean with "enable dragging"? What can be dragged? Perhaps you should add more code to your question. There is no MotionEvent for dragging, but a ACTION_MOVE event.